# Can I work multiple angular versions in my computer?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have installed Angular **7.2.0** globally on my Windows machine. Path is `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli`, and I need to run older projects like Angular **6.0.0**. So do I need to install both of versions on my machine in order to run the project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you install `@angular/cli` in each project locally using `package.json`, then you can use `npx ng` which will use the local version of the package.

So for example instead of doing: `ng serve`

You would instead do: `npx ng serve`

Comment: Agreed, but also be aware that the CLI can handle previous versions of Angular, so always use the latest version. This will only create a warning to let you know your versions aren't the same, but you can ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

every angular project has locally a version of angular cli if the global cli has different version the local one will be used so in your case the local angular cli will run and build the project.

you will got a warinig message like this

> Your global Angular CLI version (7.0.0) is greater than your local
>   version (6.0.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
>   false".

Answer (score 2):

`npx` way is good. In case if you don't have `npx` then you can direct use `ng` from `node_modules` like below

```sh
node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npx -p @angular/cli@17 ng new angular12App
```

→ it will automatically download angular cli 17 and then create project with specified version