Is it possible to work with different versions of Angular?
I have version 17 of Angular CLI installed globally on my machine, however I would like to use version 15 of Angular in a specific project, how can I do this locally without having to change the global version? What is the best practice to do in this regard?

Install the CLI as a local/project-specific dependency via npm install

how can I do this? Could you tell me the command please? remembering that it would be in version 15. @pzaenger

npm i @angular/cli@15.2.11, and then take a look at node_modules/.bin

You can check this similar answer as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630368/can-i-work-multiple-angular-versions-in-my-computer

I could use the ng update command to do this, would that be an alternative? @pzaenger

First create a new folder, say it's myProject.
Then go inside this folder and run the below npm command. Which installs the version of angular/cli you need which is different from the global version.
npm i @angular/cli@15.2.11

Now you have Angular 15 installed inside this folder, now we will use this Angular cli 15 to install the Angular project using npx command, the difference between npm and npx is that, npm uses the globally installed version of a package, but npx uses the local version of a package.
So using npx we create the angular project using Angular 15.
npx ng new testProject

Now you have an Angular 15 project to start work on. But you have to use npx commands whenever you face issues due to different version of Angular, but this is very rare scenario.

I could use the ng update command to do this, would that be an alternative? @Naren Murali

no, what I want to do is actually downgrade from version 17 to 15, with ng update is it not possible to do this? @Naren Murali

the main reason is because I have old projects on version 15 @Naren Murali

So in the case of your example above using npx, it will be necessary to use it all the time while I am using a lower version than my installed Angular CLI, correct? @Naren Murali

And in relation to my projects with versions lower than Angular CLI 17, which is the global version of my machine, will I be able to continue working on them normally?, without having to change node versions, for example. @Naren Murali

A question about installing Angular CLI versions, whenever I install a new version, is it recommended to uninstall the old one and then install the new one after clearing the cache? Or do I just update the Angular CLI globally via ng update? This ended up causing me a lot of confusion, thank you in advance for the answer @Naren Murali

What is the difference between Angular and Angular CLI? Could you explain it to me please?? @Naren Murali

I have angular CLI 17.0.0 installed globally on my machine and I am creating projects from it, but the projects created when I run the ng version command in their directory, the project's angular CLI version comes as 17.3.11, in package.json file the version is 17.0.0 equal to the global version installed on the machine @Naren Murali

Thank you very much, you help me a lot, I also have one last problem, this error started when I installed Angular CLI 17, the ng serve command runs the program, but when I click to open the page in the browser this error appears in the terminal, "Error : Service has been stopped: spawn C: my folder path @Narem Murali

detail that the path to this folder is very long, I don't know if it could be for this reason @Narem Murali

Hello, is there any difference in installing libraries using Angular's npm and ng? for example "npm i @angular/material" or "ng add @angular/material" @Naren Murali

@viniideveloper ng add will install using npm and configure the angular project to use the package , npm install simply installs the package you need to do the configuration

when integrating the front-end with the back-end we need to create a model folder with a file identical to the class that is in my back-end, with the same attributes, why is this necessary?, in this case I am giving an example of a application using angular and java. @Naren Murali
